# Function which will anonymise data with text instead of numbers

Tags: r

I have a simple custom function which anonymises data into numbers which I use to quickly anonymise data to use as sample data. Is it possible for this to return text rather than numbers?

```
anonymiser_func <- function(x) {
  match(x, sample(unique(x)))
}

Z = sample(LETTERS,10)

anonymiser_func(Z)
[1]  6  9 10  5  3  8  1  7  2  4
```

Comment: Have you checked `anonymizer` package i.e. `library(anonymizer);anonymize(Z)`

Comment: What about `function(x) LETTERS[match(x, sample(unique(x)))]`?